# Windows 8: Multilanguage on HyperLinkButton

Tags: xaml, localization, windows-runtime

In windows 8 you can set the content or text property by using : `x:UiD="SomeText"` 
This loads the text with id SomeText from a resource file.
Unfortunately this doesn't work for HyperLinkButtons, the content property isn't loaded from the resource file.

Anybody knows how to set the content of a HyperLinkButton from a resource file? 
And how to do it for other properties? Like `AutomationProperties.Name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your second question: You may use in the resource file as Name the following:
`SomeText.[using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation]AutomationProperties.Name`

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like the following:

```
<HyperlinkButton>
   <TextBlock x:UiD="SomeText" .../>
</HyperlinkButton>
```

or more detailed:

```
<HyperlinkButton>
  <HyperlinkButton.Content>
   <TextBlock x:UiD="SomeText" .../>
  </HyperlinkButton.Content>
</HyperlinkButton>
```

**Another solution**, is to provide the localized strings through your ViewModel via binding. Something like the following:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding ALocalizedLabel}"/>
 <Button AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding AnotherLocalizedLabel}" .../>
```

A drawback of this solution comes due to the minimalistic binding system of metro. You can not provide a default (fallback) value. An advantage is that it makes your XAML less confusing and more readable.